# gcc linker: KEEP is not keeping the section

Tags: gcc, linker

I am using the linker script from the MAX32660 SDK, which includes the following:

```
SECTIONS {
    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        *(.text*)    /* program code */
        *(.rodata*)  /* read-only data: "const" */

        KEEP(*(.init))
        KEEP(*(.fini))

        /* C++ Exception handling */
        KEEP(*(.eh_frame*))
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH
```

The `isr_vector` section is defined in the following assembly code:

```
    .section .isr_vector
    .align 2
    .globl __isr_vector
__isr_vector:
    .long    __StackTop            /* Top of Stack */
    .long    Reset_Handler         /* Reset Handler */
```

Wherein `Reset_Handler` initializes memory, sets up device config, and calls `main()`.

Unfortunately in some situations (e.g., no SDK functions imported from `main()`) the entire program is optimized out (binary file size is 0) unless I include the `-u__isr_vector` linker option. Why is this option required? Isn't it redundant, since I already have `KEEP(*(.isr_vector))`?

(I am not sure if `KEEP` is only for sections or also for symbols... I also tried `KEEP(*(.isr_vector*))` and `KEEP(*(.isr_vector.*))`, but I still need `-u__isr_vector`.)

Comment: Does it help when you `.section .isr_vector,"a",@progbits` ?

Comment: @emacs unfortunately the gnu assembler rejects the comma syntax.

Comment: That should be valid syntax for GNU assembler and ELF targets. The `@` is target dependent though.  If `@` has a special meaning to the assembler, some other char is used. You can find out my assembling a small C program with `-S -fdata-sections` and look in the `*.s` file. Add a global variable to the C file.